# How to extract the hour, minute and second part of a bytearray string?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a bytearray --> bytearray(b'\x07\xe3\n\n\x04\n\x0f\x00\x00\x00<\x00').

It represents a date and time field. I am able to extract the date, but not able to extract the time with AM/PM details. How to decide which format characters to use?

I am using the `struct` library with the `unpack_from` method.

```
import struct

byte_range = bytearray(b'\x07\xe3\n\n\x04\n\x0f\x00\x00\x00<\x00')
data = struct.unpack_from('!HBB',byte_range)
print(data)
```

I am also expecting an hour, minute and seconds data from it with the AM/PM details as well. The decoded date time should be `10/10/2019 1:15:00 PM`.

Comment: try unpacking more data: `struct.unpack_from('!HBBBBBBBBBB',byte_range)`

Comment: What should the result be, including the time detail values? In other words, what exactly is the format of the data in `byte_range`? These things must be know in order to parse it correctly.

Comment: @martineau You are right. The result is `10/10/2019 1:15:00 PM`. I will edit the question to add this info.

Comment: That info is useful, but it sounds like you don't know the format of the data in `byte_range`. In all hex its value is `\x07\xe3\x0a\x0a\x04\x0a\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x3c\x00`, and aside from the first four bytes, it not obvious how to get `1:15:00 PM` out of the remaining ones. **That's** the key issue. What format is the time of day being stored in?

Answer (score 0):

The shape of a datetime tuple is `(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, ...)`.

Looking at the size of each [format character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) and knowing how big each part of the datetime is, you can figure out what format character you need.

For the specific case, you have already chosen the right format characters for the date:

- `B` is an unsigned char, 1 byte, value range: 0 to 255
- `H` is an unsigned short, 2 bytes, value range: 0 to 65535

As you can see `B` is too small to store the value for the year, that's why you need an `H`.

Now, you know that the time is composed by 3 number whose value range is 0 to 60, thus `B` is what you need for all of them, ending up with the format `!HBBBBB`.

Here is the result:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> import struct
>>> byte_range = bytearray(b'\x07\xe3\n\n\x04\n\x0f\x00\x00\x00<\x00')
>>> date_tuple = struct.unpack_from('!HBBBBB', byte_range)
>>> date = datetime.datetime(*date_tuple)
>>> date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')
'2019-10-10 04:10 AM'
```

A [table showing the size of the C integer types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) might be useful

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However, from the data I see that the actual date is `10/10/2019 1:15:00 PM`. So certainly we are going wrong with the format characters.

Comment: Are we talking about the same input you provided in the question? It sounds strange